# Get Access Token from Microsoft Graph API using PHP

Tags: php, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I want to sync my outlook 365 calendar events with my system.
My system is a background service, not an application, therefore i can't provide a login screen for the user to approve authorization.

I'm following this link in order to get an access token
[Get access without a user](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_service)

I have called this link through the browser (pasted manually), in order to approve admin permissions, got an approval screen and approved admin permissions:
`https://login.microsoftonline.com/mycompany.onmicrosoft.com/adminconsent?client_id=xxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx&state=12345&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fmyserver.mycompany.com%2Fsugarcrmmaintest%2Fresponse.php`

The response url was called as planned and I received a response.

Now I want to get the access token.
I've been calling this code, according to the manual, but nothing happens and I don't get a response

```php
$clientId = "xxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx";
$clientSecret = "mysecret";
$responseUri = "https%3A%2F%2Fmyserver.mycompany.com%2Fsugarcrmmaintest%2Fresponse.php";


$postUrl = "/mycomp.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/token";
$hostname = "login.microsoftonline.com";
$fullurl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/mycompany.onmicrosoft.com/token";

$headers = array(
    "POST " . $postUrl . " HTTP/1.1",
    "Host: " . $hostname,
    "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
);

$post_params = array(
    "client_id" => $clientId,
    "scope" => "https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default",
    "client_secret" => $clientSecret,
    "grant_type" => "client_credentials",
);

$curl = curl_init($fullurl);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_params);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$response = curl_exec($curl);
```

Did I forget something?

This is the explanation in the training page:

[image]
I have read tens of posts here, but all of them are examples that involve an authorization screen which I can't provide. I need the sync to work as a background service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I would double-check the URL you are sending in through cURL. I would try testing it with `https://login.microsoftonline.com/mycompany.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/token`. You may be overwriting it in the header when you call `CURLOPT_HEADER` twice.
2. Try setting `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);` if you are working in a dev environment.

Comment: Agree with you. When we do a test, we can just use the https://login.microsoftonline.com/mycompany.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/token for the URL directly. Even you want to add a head in the request, you can just add`"Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`. Others are not needed.

Comment: yes. started communicating with the microsoft graph as soon as i replaced "https://login.microsoftonline.com/mycompany.onmicrosoft.com/token" with "https://login.microsoftonline.com/mycompany.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/token". now i at least get an error replay back to my POST request. so thank you. i'm getting error: "AADSTS90014: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'grant_type'" although i sent the grant_type in the body... and with the right value as the traning page say so. does anyone know why? (at least i started to communicate with the graph..:))

Comment: I was not able to pass through credentials with an associative array, but using a plain text body works fine:
```php
    $body = "grant_type=client_credentials" .
        "&client_id=" . $applicationId . 
        "&client_secret=" . $applicationSecret .
        "&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default";
```

Answer (score 2):

There are many methods to achieve this. The following example is using Microsoft **[Graph SDK for PHP](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-php#get-started-with-the-microsoft-graph-sdk-for-php)**

> The Microsoft Graph SDK for PHP does not include any default
>   authentication implementations. The [thenetworg/oauth2-azure library](https://github.com/thenetworg/oauth2-azure)
>   will handle standard Oauth2 for you, and provide a usable token for
>   querying the Graph.

To authenticate as an application you can use the [Guzzle HTTP client](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/), which comes preinstalled with this library, for example like this:

```
$guzzle = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$url = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/' . $tenantId . '/oauth2/v2.0/token';
$token = json_decode($guzzle->post($url, [
    'form_params' => [
        'client_id' => $clientId,
        'client_secret' => $clientSecret,
        'scope' => 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default',
        'grant_type' => 'client_credentials',
    ],
])->getBody()->getContents());
$accessToken = $token->access_token;
```

You can also use [thephpleague/oauth2-client](https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-client) for Authenticate the user and get an access token.

[Here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/php#authenticate-the-user-and-get-an-access-token) is a example for Authorization code grant flow example.But you can also [use client_credentials flow](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/php#authenticate-the-user-and-get-an-access-token) for it.

Please let me know if it helps!